# Need run scripts as different users on same host to different hosts without password prompt

Tags: server, bash, ssh, login, password

I need to run scripts with different linux users on same host to different hosts without password prompt. In other words, the deferent users are on a source host able to login (ssh/scp/other shell scripts) to other hosts without password prompt.

The following is example:

hostA-user1, hostA-user2, hostA-user3 … on hostA:  able to execute shell “uname –a”  on hostB and hostC

hosts-user as a common user on hostB which allows others user login from different hosts. 
hosts-user as a common user on hostC, hostD and etc. which allows others user login from different hosts.

But I do not want setup ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on hostB, hostC and etc. for each users on hostA and do not want users:hostA-user* to get password prompt when login and/or run scripts from hostA.  Any option to do so?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered installing kerberos and LDAP with single sign-on?  Once they have logged in on HostA their credentials are stored and they can login to HostB (HostC .etc) without a prompt.

Personally I like ssh using ssh-agent to store my credentials and then I can login all over the network without bother.  But that requires using .ssh/authorized_keys, which you stated you didn't want to do.  I use this to run scripts across the network (scripts which don't need root access).

Comment: Thanks for response.  I use the .ssh/authorized_keys for my personal use. In this case, I need setup the all hostA users can run the script on different hosts which they do not have .ssh/authorized_keys setup. 

The SSO is another option. I also see the http method  by using “curl” can run the script without login.  I just do not know how to do it – more digging